# Unexpected Token in SQL CONCAT statement

Tags: sql, concatenation

I'm working on learning SQL for a certification program I'm in and trying to make a CONCAT statement.

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    NOC
    CONCAT(Event, " ", Discipline) AS Team
FROM 
    Table1
```

When I run this in LibreOffice Base, I get an error

> Unexpected token (, requires FROM in statement [SELECT NOC
> CONCAT(]

I've done just about everything I know how to do with the syntax that I know how to do; I've added a comma after SELECT NOC, I've tried adding semicolons, removing parentheses and so on and they all return different errors. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

To clarify, `Event` and `Discipline` are columns in my table, not strings.

Comment: What's `NOC` supposed to be? A column?

Comment: Yes, NOC is another column.

Comment: You missed the comma after NOC.

Answer (score 2):

The quotes need to be single quotes:

- `CONCAT(Event, ' ', Discipline)`

Also there should be a comma after NOC (assuming it's a column in Table1), and Event is a reserved word. This query should work in an SQL query tool (e.g. SQL Management Studio)

```
SELECT 
  NOC,
  CONCAT([Event],' ', Discipline) AS Team
FROM 
  Table1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. Unfortunately switching to single quotes for the CONCAT statement didn't affect my error, and adding the comma after NOC gave me the following error: S1000 General error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 in statement [SELECT "NOC", CONCAT( "Event", ' ', "Discipline" )]
Following your advice worked just fine using BigQuery though, so maybe it's just an issue with LibreOffice.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I´m not familiar with LibreOffice but this will work in a SQL query tool.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @mvpstudios - You're clearly using code or cell formulae to create your SQL Statement.  For example, the answer here does NOT have double-quotes around the column names, in your error message, however, they're present.  If you open a ***separate*** question explaining how you use LibreOffice to create that SQL Statement, we'll be happy to help you diagnose that problem.  As for the SQL problem posed in this question, this answer is clearly correct and as such should be accepted as correct.